# Mutual independence, normal distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

Given three random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$ which are $N(m,\sigma^2), N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $N(m+\mu,\sigma^2)$ respectively for some $m, \mu, \sigma$, does it follow that $X, Y, Z$ are mutually independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for example $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $Y=\mu+X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ has the whiched property but they are not independent.

Comment: How would I show such $X, Y$ are not independent?

Comment: $Y$ depend on $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much.